# Why is is saying volume not defined?

Tags: javascript, function, class, object

Getting an error of illegal return statement on the volume...

tried adding CuboidMaker15.volume to call the object

```
class CuboidMaker15 {
    constructor(cuboidMaker15Attributes){
      this.length = cuboidMaker15Attributes.length;
      this.width = cuboidMaker15Attributes.width;
      this.height = cuboidMaker15Attributes.height;
    }
}
   volume(); {
    return this.length * this.width * this.height;
  }

surfaceArea(); {
  return 2 * (this.length * this.width + this.length * this.height + this.width * this.height);
}

const cuboid15 = new CuboidMaker15({
  length: 4,
  width: 5,
  height: 5
});
```

Keeps saying the volume is not defined...

Comment: Why is there a `;` after the () ?? Hint, that is your problem....

Comment: You are closing `{}` of your class before adding methods. And remove `;` after `volume()` and `surfaceArea()`

Comment: Still getting the same error..

Comment: and removing the semicolons made more error some up, those are needed.

Comment: because your `class` methods are not inside of the class

Comment: The reason more errors appear is because with the semi-colons your code never made it far enough to throw those other errors. I think [reviewing classes syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) might help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Khauri and Maheer, I take that back. The semi-colons did need to be removed. Tom hit it on the head with his example though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your methods inside your class definition. Also get rid of `;` after the method name:

```js
class CuboidMaker15 {
  constructor(cuboidMaker15Attributes) {
    this.length = cuboidMaker15Attributes.length;
    this.width = cuboidMaker15Attributes.width;
    this.height = cuboidMaker15Attributes.height;
  }
  volume() {
    return this.length * this.width * this.height;
  }

  surfaceArea() {
    return 2 * (this.length * this.width + this.length * this.height + this.width * this.height);
  }
}

const cuboid15 = new CuboidMaker15({
  length: 4,
  width: 5,
  height: 5
});


console.log(cuboid15);
console.log(cuboid15.volume());
console.log(cuboid15.surfaceArea());
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote but it won't register because my rep is not at 15. Thanks a super duper bunch dude!